# Problemas importando proyecto Vue-cli como librería en un proyecto Vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, component, vuetify, vue-cli

Estoy trabajando en un "Design System / Storybook" en un proyecto Vue-cli y quiero validar cómo se comportaría importándolo como librería en un proyecto Vue-cli simple.

Según la documentación de Vue-cli y algunas guías que he encontrado, he seguido los pasos siguientes:

- Cambiar el fichero "main.js" que exporta los componentes para formar la librería (código abajo)
- Construir la librería de componentes mediante el comando de vue-cli-service script con la opción de "pack" porque no puedo publicar este proyecto en NPM (debe ser privado), de modo que lo tengo que probar en local
- Importar el paquete en el proyecto simple vue-cli

Aparentemente todo funciona ok, el proyecto se compila bien, se genera el fichero comprimido, en el otro proyecto al instalarlo se importa de forma correcta, pero cuando renderizo el proyecto simple vue-cli me aparece en consola el error siguiente:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Alert>
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Nota: Alert es uno de mis componentes del proyecto Storybook

Algunos detalles de mi proyecto Storybook:

**Storybook package-json.js**

```
{
  "name": "my-custom-storybook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/my-custom-storybook.common.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/my-custom-storybook.umd.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --inline-vue --name my-custom-storybook ./src/main.js && npm pack && mv ./my-custom-storybook-0.1.0.tgz ../",
    "test:unit": "jest -u",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src './src/**/*.?(js|vue)' --locales './src/locales/**/*.json'",
    "storybook:build": "vue-cli-service storybook:build -c config/storybook",
    "storybook:serve": "vue-cli-service storybook:serve -p 6006 -c config/storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import Alert from '@/components/customComponents/Alert'
import Button from '@/components/uiComponents/Button'

export {
  Alert,
  Button
}

export default {
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.component('Alert', Alert)
    Vue.component('Button', Button)
  }
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: true
    }
  }
}
```

**Componente Alert**

```
<template>
  <v-alert
    type="warning"
    close-icon="$vuetify.icons.small"
    light
    dense
    text
  >
    <strong> {{ title }} </strong>
    {{ message }}
  </v-alert>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Alert',
  props: {
    /**
     * Setup the title to appear on alert component
     */
    title: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    },
    /**
     * Setup the message to appear on alert component
     */
    message: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

En el otro proyecto, para instalar la librería e importarla en la página deseada utilizo las instrucciones siguientes:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
    <Alert message="Error on doing thingies" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Alert from "my-custom-storybook";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    Alert
  }
};
</script>
```

¿Qué está fallando? ¿Hay alguna configuración que no he tenido en cuenta? ¿Necesito añadir más configuraciones? Estoy totalmente perdida en este asunto, necesito ayuda por favor T_T

Gracias a todxs!
Saludos